# Firebase Phone Auth SHA-1 fingerprint Issue

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I had created a sign in page in flutter using phone Authentication. In which i am getting the error:

**E/FirebaseAuth(21546): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console.
I/flutter (21546): This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console. ]**

I had already get the SHA1 and SHA256 key from the cmd by using the following steps:

1. In cmd, visited the path where java jdk is installed(in my case:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212)
2. Then pasted the following command and hit enter
   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Mehul Jain.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

After that i got the key as shown in Screenshot.

[image: SHA1 Key]

copied both the keys and pasted in the firebase Console (as shown in Screenshot below)
[image: firebase console]

App is working correctly. And when I tried signing through test mode (i.e. entering the mobile no. and otp) and run the app with the test mode details, the app was working 100%.
But if I want to add the mobile number from the app and try to get SMS the error comes on the screen. I had tried various other mobile number but still not worked(mobile number are not entered in test mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if are using emulator then safety net fails make sure you using a  legitimate with Android Device
- it is possible that u using wrong keystore. best method for fnding
  debug SHA key is **Gradle >> signinreport>>rightclick>>run**

[image]

Comment: Yes, from gradile SigningReport different SHA1 key is genrated. But then in CMD why does it shows another key?

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you to use this free library [OTP_VERIFICATION API](https://github.com/ErrorxCode/OTP-Verification-Api)
I have also tried this, and it is the simplest API ever.**